# $.mobile.changePage without ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi for navigating  from one page to another i used `$.mobile.changePage('test.html');`. This works fine in android,symbian and blackberry6+.But I also want my application to run on blackberry5. Blackberry5 does not support ajax and therefore `$.mobile.changePage('test.html');` not work for it.

For this reason I use `window.open("test.html");` and `window.location.href = "test.html";`  Here it works perfectly in all platform including blackberry4.6+ also.  But now problem is I have header in test.html as:

```
     <div data-role="header" align="center">

        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
            <h1>Test.html</h1>
        <a href="MainMenu.html"  data-icon="grid">Menu</a>


    </div>
```

But here now back button is not working. If I use `$.mobile.changePage('test.html');` for navigation then back button works perfectly but not with `window.open("test.html");` and `window.location.href = "test.html";`.

Therefore I use session and on click of back button I call page forcefully. as:

```
<script type="application/javascript">

            function redirect(url)
            {
                alert("inside redirect:"+url);
                window.location = url;
            }

        </script>

        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>

                <li> <a onclick="redirect( getCookie('paged'))" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Back</a></li>
                <li> <a onclick="redirect(getCookie('paged'))" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Back</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Here now back button also works perfectly but when I click on hardware back button then it again goes to previous pages from where it came.

How I can use `$.mobile.changePage(...)` without ajax so I can use it for all platforms including blackberry4.6+

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to disable ajax using the Global Config but it didn't work out for me for some reason.

I tried as below and it worked

```
window.location.href="myfile.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the global property `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled` to `false`? See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html. It is written that "jQuery Mobile will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax, when possible". I am not sure now if it does also affect `$.mobile.changePage`, but maybe it is worth a try...

Comment: I tried with '$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;   ' but no luck. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function.

```
$.mobile.changePage('#gototestpage');
```

But there is some restriction. You will have to keep the code in same page in another div like so,

```
<div id="gototestpage"> --- Your Code here ----- </div>
```

Comment: Blackberry5 does not support ajax therefore I cant use $.mobile.changePage.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this two solutions, both worked for me:

```
window.location.href = yourpageurl;
```

or

```
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "change", yourpageurl);
```